# Quarkus graalvm native build dockerfile installation fails

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I want to deploy a quarkus builder image via a Dockerfile. We are behind a proxy, I set all the linux proxy settings in upper- and lowercase.

**If I run the Dockerfile, I get an error message at the gu command to install the native image component**. Here is the complete run statement in the Dockerfile:

```
# Install GraalVM
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/oracle/graal/releases/download/vm-${GRAALVM_VERSION}/graalvm-ce-linux-amd64-${GRAALVM_VERSION}.tar.gz > graalvm-ce-${GRAALVM_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf graalvm-ce-${GRAALVM_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    rm -f graalvm-ce-${GRAALVM_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    mv graalvm-ce-${GRAALVM_VERSION} /usr/lib/jvm/ && \
    cd /usr/lib/jvm && \
    ln -sfn graalvm-ce-${GRAALVM_VERSION} graalvm && \
    alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${GRAALVM_HOME}bin/java 97

RUN printenv
RUN ${GRAALVM_HOME}bin/gu install native-image
```

It returns an error message containing that I have to set an http_proxy. Before that run statement I start a printenv statement, as I can see the http_proxy env variable is set.
Before and after that part of the dockerfile we download and install other stuff. That works.

**The only thing that don't work is the gu statement.**

Here is the returning log message:

```
Step 10/24 : RUN printenv
 ---> Running in e539ee727135
...
GRAALVM_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/
HTTP_PROXY=http://This-is-a:real@proxy.com:8080/
http_proxy=http://This-is-a:real@proxy.com:8080/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://This-is-a:real@proxy.com:8080/
https_proxy=http://This-is-a:real@proxy.com:8080/
GRAALVM_VERSION=19.2.1
...
Removing intermediate container e539ee727135
 ---> de3d463af567
Step 11/24 : RUN ${GRAALVM_HOME}bin/gu available
 ---> Running in d4a04b82279c
Downloading: Component catalog from www.graalvm.org
Error: Error downloading component catalog from https://www.graalvm.org/component-catalog/graal-updater-component-catalog.properties: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address.
Please check your connection and proxy settings. If your machine is behind a proxy, environment variables (http_proxy, https_proxy, ...) must be set appropriately.
The command '/bin/sh -c ${GRAALVM_HOME}bin/gu install native-image' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

Comment: I think it's worth opening an issue in the GraalVM tracker asking to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Found not really a solution, but a workaround. 
I fetched the component manually and install it via local statement. 
 Here is the Dockerfile snippet to install the native build:

```
### Install GraalVM native build
RUN curl -fsL -o component.jar https://github.com/oracle/graal/releases/download/vm-${GRAALVM_VERSION}/native-image-installable-svm-linux-amd64-${GRAALVM_VERSION}.jar && \
    ${GRAALVM_HOME}bin/gu install -L component.jar && \
    rm component.jar
```

That works.